# Condensing forecast in Pandas using column identifier

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting

I have a Pandas dataframe which contains weekly forecasts for products (product information contained in the first two columns) - see the below example.

```
prod_type    prod_version    26-04-2021    03-05-2021    10-05-2021    17-05-2021    24-05-2021

product1          a              0            100           100           100           100

product1          b              0            200           100           400           100

product1          a             100           200           300           100           100

product2          a              0             0            500            0            100

product2          b             100           200           300           100           100

product2          b             200           400           300           800            0
```

I am looking for the most efficient way to condense the forecast rows, i.e. product 1, version a is left with just the one  row which is the sum of the corresponding column values. The final output should look something like this:

```
prod_type    prod_version    26-04-2021    03-05-2021    10-05-2021    17-05-2021    24-05-2021

product1          a             100           300           400           200           200

product1          b              0            200           100           400           100

product2          a              0             0            500            0            100

product2          b             300           600           600           900           100
```

I've been playing around with some groupby.transform('sum') methods but nothing seems to stick. Does anyone have any suggestions on how best to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use multiple column in **groupby**

```
df.groupby(['prod_type','prod_version']).sum()
```